# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in PATCH AJAX request in React-Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to update a basic database via a form in my app. The update is handled through this AJAX call:

```
handleUpdate (e) {
  let url = '/sites/' + this.props.site.id;
  let site = {
    name: this.refs.name.value,
    city: this.refs.city.value,
    state: this.refs.state.value,
    country: this.refs.country.value,
  };
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'PATCH',
    url: url,
    data: {site: site},
    success: (site) => {
      console.log("success");
    }
  });
}
```

Controller:

```
def update 
    @site = Site.find(params[:id]) 
    if @site.update_attributes(site_params) 
        redirect_to('index') 
    else 
        render('edit') 
    end 
end
```

When I click to update, I receive this error:

> PATCH http://localhost:3000/sites/2 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE   jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:10246

However, when I refresh the page, the update is made to the database, and the updated value is shown.

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code for that update controller action

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot!

Comment: `def update
  @site = Site.find(params[:id])

  if @site.update_attributes(site_params)
   redirect_to('index')
  else
   render('edit')
  end
 end`